# How can I check for or cancel MULTIPLE pending application.ontime events in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ontime

I'm using the Application.Ontime event to pull a time field from a cell, and schedule a subroutine to run at that time.  My Application.Ontime event runs on the Workbook_BeforeSave event.  As such, if a user **(changes the desired time + saves the workbook)** multiple times, multiple Application.Ontime events are created.  Theoretically I could keep track of each event with a unique time variable.. but is there a way to check/parse/cancel pending events?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave
    SendTime = Sheets("Email").Range("B9")
    Application.OnTime SendTime, "SendEmail"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose
    Application.OnTime SendTime, "SendEmail", , False
End Sub
```

So if I:
change B9 to 12:01, Save the workbook
change B9 to 12:03, Save the workbook
change B9 to 12:05, Save the workbook
change B9 to 12:07, Save the workbook
etc

I end up with multiple events firing.  I only want ONE event to fire (the most recently scheduled one)

How can I cancel ALL pending events (or enumerate them at least) on the Workbook_BeforeClose event?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you collect the SendTime value during the BeforeSave event? Why not, say, the Workbook_SheetChange event?

Comment: Good suggestion!  Hadn't even considered it.  I'm a VBA newbie.  Thanks!

Comment: I also want to mention that it's generally not a good idea to use Sheets("Email") because a user could change the sheet name and break your macro. Instead, use the sheet's code name.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion too! Had to Google it, but I'll make the change.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can iterate through all pending events or cancel them all in one shabang. I'd suggest setting a module level or global boolean indicating whether or not to fire your event. So you'd end up with something like this:

```
Dim m_AllowSendMailEvent As Boolean
Sub SendMail()
If Not m_AllowSendMailEvent Then Exit Sub

'fire event here

End Sub
```

### Edit:

Add this to the TOP of the sheet module which contains the range which contains the date/time value you're after:

```
' Most recently scheduled OnTime event. (Module level variable.)
Dim PendingEventDate As Date

' Indicates whether an event has been set. (Module level variable.)
Dim EventSet As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim SendTimeRange As Range

' Change to your range.
Set SendTimeRange = Me.Range("B9")

' If the range that was changed is the same as that which holds
' your date/time field, schedule an OnTime event.
If Target = SendTimeRange Then

    ' If an event has previously been set AND that time has not yet been
    ' reached, cancel it. (OnTime will fail if the EarliestTime parameter has
    ' already elapsed.)
    If EventSet And Now > PendingEventDate Then

        ' Cancel the event.
        Application.OnTime PendingEventDate, "SendEmail", , False

    End If

    ' Store the new scheduled OnTime event.
    PendingEventDate = SendTimeRange.Value

    ' Set the new event.
    Application.OnTime PendingEventDate, "SendEmail"

    ' Indicate that an event has been set.
    EventSet = True

End If

End Sub
```

And this to a standard module:

```
Sub SendEmail()

    'add your proc here

End Sub
```

Comment: I wish I could just do :  
If Application.OnTime Then
Application.OnTime , , , False

Comment: Could you please explain if/how setting a global boolean might help me ensure that only one event fires?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you an example of what you could do.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call Application.Ontime save the time the event is set to run (you could save it on a sheet or in a module scoped dynamic array)

Each time your event fires, remove the corresponding saved time

To cancel all pending event iterate through the remaining saved times calling Application.Ontime with schedule = false

Comment: I really like this idea, but I'm a VBA newb.  I'm sure I can figure it out, but if you have time to give a bit of example code i'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: specifically, the dynamic array.. how would I append each new time to the array?

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have a solution that works, based on some of the advice already given.

In short, we create a global array and each time the user hits `save` the SendTime is written to the array. This serves to keep track of all our scheduled times.

When the workbook is closed, we loop through the array and delete all scheduled times.

I tested this and it seemed to work on Excel 2003. Let me know how you get on.

```
Dim scheduleArray() As String //Set as global array to hold times

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave
    SendTime = Sheets("Email").Range("B9")
    AddToScheduleArray SendTime
    Application.OnTime SendTime, "SendEmail"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim iArr As Integer, startTime As String

    For iArr = 0 To UBound(scheduleArray) - 1 //Loop through array and delete any existing scheduled actions 
        startTime = scheduleArray(iArr)
        Application.OnTime TimeValue(startTime), "SendEmail", , False
    Next iArr
End Sub

Sub AddToScheduleArray(startTime As String)
    Dim arrLength As Integer

    If Len(Join(scheduleArray)) < 1 Then
        arrLength = 0
    Else
        arrLength = UBound(scheduleArray)
    End If

    ReDim Preserve scheduleArray(arrLength + 1) //Resize array
    scheduleArray(arrLength) = startTime //Add start time
End Sub
```

Comment: This still results in more than one event firing, no?

Comment: Yes - re-reading the question I see only one event should fire i.e. the most recently created and that all pending events should be cancelled on close. I'll update my code to that effect...

Answer (score 1):

or you can just create some cell (like abacus), for example:

if I use application.ontime:

```
if range("V1") < 1 then

    Application.OnTime dTime, "MyMacro"

    range("V1")=range("V1") + 1

 end if
```

if I want to stop counting...

```
   Application.OnTime dTime, "MyMacro", , False

   range("V1")=range("V1") - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am missing something, but why not just cancel a call before you start a new one?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave
    On Error Resume Next 'this is here for the first call when there is nothing yet to cancel
    Application.OnTime SendTime, "SendEmail", , False
    SendTime = Sheets("Email").Range("B9")
    Application.OnTime SendTime, "SendEmail"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose
    Application.OnTime SendTime, "SendEmail", , False
End Sub
```

*assuming `SendTime` is a global variable

This results in only one Call running at any given time - and if I understood the question right, that is the desired behaviour.