# Excel vba close after time

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Does anyone know any VBA code that will close and save an excel file after a delay? I tried some `kutools` code that was supposed to close only after some idle time but it closes without checking for inactivity.

Comment: Using `Application.OnTime` you can schedule a Macro to close the Workbook,  See [Chip Pearson's - OnTime](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ontime.aspx)

Comment: In addition to using `OnTime`, You should be clearing the previous `OnTime` events to get only the last event to be active. You may want to check this link for some useful ideas: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599796/how-can-i-check-for-or-cancel-multiple-pending-application-ontime-events-in-exce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste in Routine Module:

```
Option Explicit

Const idleTime = 30 'seconds
Dim Start
Sub StartTimer()
Start = Timer
Do While Timer < Start + idleTime
    DoEvents
Loop
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Step 1: Declare your variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Step 2: Unhide the Starting Sheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
'Step 3: Start looping through all worksheets
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'Step 4: Check each worksheet name
If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
'Step 5: Hide the sheet
ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
End If
'Step 6: Loop to next worksheet
Next ws
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Range("A1").Select

ThisWorkbook.Save

'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Paste in ThisWorkbook :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    StartTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: The time only resets when changing sheet? Because it iwll be a userform to input data.

Answer (score 0):

Paste in Routine Module:

```
    Sub Reset()
Static SchedSave
    If SchedSave <> 0 Then
    Application.OnTime SchedSave, "SaveWork", , False
    End If
    SchedSave = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")     '<--- Ten minutes
    Application.OnTime SchedSave, "SaveWork", , True
End Sub

Sub SaveWork()
MsgBox "Run the close workbook macro here."
'ThisWorkbook.Save
'Application.Quit
'ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Paste in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Reset
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Reset
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Reset
End Sub
```

Timer will start automatically when workbook is opened. Presently set for 10 minutes (can be adjusted). Closing macro code has been disabled and presently replaced with a MsgBox notice.