# open csv as txt file from excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to open a `csv` file as `txt` format from a `VBA` macro like this without success:

```
Open "F:\MyPlace\Content\1 - IMPORTER.csv" For Output As #1
```

My goal is to open this file, (as stated) outside the excel. Just like you open a txt file.

Would this be possible? How?

Comment: Do you want the contents of the `.csv` to be input to a worksheet or do you want to open the file with something like *Notepad*

Comment: csv is a text file. Just drag&drop it onto Notepad.

Comment: Would you like to extract and process (input output content) the extracted string? Or only opening it in a text editor? Which looks less probable to me, looking to your code...

Comment: Besides, you open the file for output, so can write anything to it you want with `write #1` or `print #1`

Comment: What would you like doing **after opening** it? In this way, maybe we will better understand your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, please:

```
Sub WHATEVER()
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open ("C:\Users\beckj\whatever.txt")
End Sub
```

Comment: Just one more thing... (if I may ask..?): Do you know how can I save and close this object after a certain time?

Comment: @bpy , that's interesting. I've never tried that. But it appears that this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452247/14010152